# What word describes a house without anyone inside?

Tags: single-word-requests

If all occupants left a house for a short period of time (not longer than a day), how can that house be described?

Comment: I would call it a *temporarily empty house*.

Comment: What's your motivation?

Comment: I think this is general reference. The potential difference in nuance between an *unoccupied house* and an *empty house* seems clear to me. It's also clear OP is familiar with the word *occupant*, so it should be easy for him to grasp this distinction.

Comment: ripe for the picking?

Comment: The phrase "temporarily empty house" sounds awkward though. I posted this question because I want to be concise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unoccupied

> un·oc·cu·pied/ˌənˈäkyəˌpīd/ Adjective:     (of ground) Not occupied by
>   inhabitants. (of premises) Having fixtures and furniture but no
>   inhabitants or occupants.

Comment: The word "unoccupied" can ignore the duration. Check this link http://feliciaawilliams.suite101.com/vacant-or-unoccupied-house-whats-the-difference-a162693

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain what they thought was wrong with the answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since words like *unoccupied* and *vacant* bear a connotation of a more extended time, I think at least in an informal context I would say:  "a house where no one is home" or similar.

Answer (score -1):

There's also vacant or vacated.

Comment: While one of the definitions of vacant is unoccupied, in addition to being unoccupied, these terms also imply the house has no furniture or other contents, and/or is not being used. The OP is looking for short-term absences.